# Marron glacé / Candied chestnuts breaking up. How to avoid this?

Tags: dessert, chestnuts

I always use frozen chestnuts to make marrons glacés since I can find those all year long (not only during winter) and because they're already pealed.

I can cook them in simmering water without making them split or break up. But they always start breaking up on the third or fourth day when candying them.
How can I prevent them from breaking into pieces and keep them whole?

When I candy them, it's 75% sugar, 25% water, brought to boiling point. I turn off the heat, wait for the boiling to stop, and put the basket inside the pot. And wait 24 hours before next plunge.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not made Marron Glaces. However I have been researching how to make them and found someone, who had used a washed onion bag to put the chestnuts in to stop them breaking up. Apparently this works. So even though I have not made them I saw your question while researching and thought I would pass on this tip to you. Hope it works for you.

Deborah

Comment: Good idea. I'll try this winter this technique.

Comment: I've looked up this method. By putting the chestnuts two by two wrapped in custom small onion bags (normal onion bags cut to size) and using string to close them up I had much less breakage than usual.

This technique works pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but I'm assuming the sugar concentration in the syrup that you're using is *way* too high.  After a few days, the water evaporates off and the sugar is left in a crystalline form inside the chestnuts.

This makes them very brittle at which point you see the breaking.

If this is the case, I can recommend two things:

- Reduce the rate at which the sugar in your confections crystallizes; left in the open air, you're going to lose moisture which is part of the problem.
- Increase the water ratio.  I'd start with a simple syrup (1 part water to 1 part sugar) and move up and down from there.  Of course, your going to sacrifice some sweetness as a result, and you don't want *too* much water, as you'll end up making the chestnuts too soft.  You'll have to adjust the balance to your tastes/tolerances.